# Securing a static SQL query from SQL Injection

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement, sql-injection, fortify

I have an application which reads thousands of flat files containing database parameters and static SQL statements. In my java code i take the SQL statement and execute it. This is not acceptable to Fortify due to probable SQL Injection vulnerability.
e.g. my flat file is something like below:

```
query: SELECT USER_ID FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE ID='2'
```

I take the `query` and execute it.

My question is how can i make such static SQLs safe?
Is there a way to convert these SQLs into PreparedStatements?

Comment: So the ENTIRE statement gets executed? I don't think qualified as SQL injection. Probably relates more to security around what queries one can execute. Maybe set up a special application user in the database with limited permissions (e.g. can only read from the database, not create/update/delete anything). Or if you want to hide certain data, expose only views on the database that can be selected, rather than the tables in entirety.
You'd also want a layer of security protecting the file against edits.

Comment: How is the file generated

Comment: @Luke Yes you are right that this does not qualify as SQL injection as the flat file is secured for any such edit that will cause some security issues. The only this is with fortify scan which comes up with the vulnerability.

Comment: @Strawberry it is a hand written file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't alter the SQL statements read from your file based on user input, then there is no SQL injection.

On the other hand, if you don't have tight control over what can end up in this file (who can edit it?), then the whole program is a huge SQL injector.

You can make your code review tool happy by using PreparedStatement even if there are no bind parameters. This of course does not improve security in any way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems i have only one option to make such a query as PreparedStatement, buit still is there any automated procedure that can convert my static sql to PreparedStatement and Fortify is also happy with that.

Comment: Why do you need a procedure? Is it more complex than `conn.prepareStatement(sqlFromFile).execute()` ?

Comment: I think i am getting very sceptic with this SQL injection. You solution will be enough that i can provide in java and it will even satisfy Fortify. I need to concentrate more on how to secure the flat file. If that gets to the attacker he can manipulate it as much he can. 
Thanks again for helping me out :)

Comment: One note, Prepared Statement by itself will not make Fortify happy. It will expect you to use ? wildcards in the query definition and then do set actions to insert the actual data. This separates the data from the SQL Query preventing SQL Injection. If you trust the controls that protect the text file and the chance of an attacker editing that file is remote, you can use Fortify's Audit Guide to trust the file system. By default, Fortify considers the file system to not be a trusted source of data. There's a check box in the Audit Guide that will change that assumption.